# Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path ... (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, download, dio

I'm trying to download *.xlsx file using dio.download, and it's throwing the errors:
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.foodagator_app/files/file.xlsx' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Another one error from try/catch block:
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'File: '' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)

I wrote the permission in androidmanifest for external storage, and also tried temporary directory, but it's not working. Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code

```
void download() async {
    var tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = File(tempDir!.path + '/file.xlsx');
    try {
      Response response = await dio.download(
        url,
        file,
        options: Options(
          responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
          followRedirects: false,
        ),
      );

      var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
      // response.data is List<int> type
      raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
      await raf.close();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error is: $e');
    }
  }

  void readFile() async {
    var tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

    var filePath = tempDir!.path + "/file.xlsx";
    var bytes = File(filePath).readAsBytesSync();
    var decoder = SpreadsheetDecoder.decodeBytes(bytes, update: true);
    for (var table in decoder.tables.keys) {
      print(table);
      print(decoder.tables[table]!.maxCols);
      print(decoder.tables[table]!.maxRows);
      for (var row in decoder.tables[table]!.rows) {
        print('$row');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is getting because there is no file named **file.xlsx** you can check if file exists or not

```
if(file.existsSync())
```

if file does not exist, you can create one using,

```
new File('$path/file.xlsx').create(recursive: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

in android 11 and higher use below permission, without  `tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"`

```
   <uses-permission 
  android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For Flutter use

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

await Hive.initFlutter(directory.path);
```

Of course, you need to

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();    
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
Hive.init(directory.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused because I had moved a dart file to another folder but my other files were still referencing that file using the old path, you can import the file again using the new path and using the "package:" keyword to solve this error.

Moral: Don't use relative paths to import a file anywhere in your project, always use the "package:" scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a custom name as well.

```
String createDownloadDocName(){
    return'${fileName}-${DateTime.now().microsecond}';
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).